# Resort array in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

I'm trying to create a function that will sort this form of array (originally with dynamic values):

```
Array
(
    [0] => product_cat-24
    [1] => style_cat-97
    [2] => style_cat-98
    [3] => stone_count_cat-110
    [4] => style_cat-100
    [5] => style_cat-104
    [6] => stone_count_cat-109
    [7] => stone_count_cat-111
)
```

So it will look like this:

```
Array(
    'product_cat'       => array( 24 ),
    'style_cat'         => array( 97, 98, 100, 104 ),
    'stone_count_cat'   => array( 110, 109, 111 )
);
```

The only thing that matters is to assign the number to its proper key.

Looking for the must elegant way to achieve that.

Thanks! :)

Comment: This is not sorting, so write your own function. If there will be problems - ask.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply try like this with [explode()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) and [list()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.list.php) of PHP.

```
<?php
$array  = array
    (
    'product_cat-24',
    'style_cat-97',
    'style_cat-98',
    'stone_count_cat-110',
    'style_cat-100',
    'style_cat-104',
    'stone_count_cat-109',
    'stone_count_cat-111'
);

$new = array();
foreach($array as $val) {
    list($key, $value) = explode('-', $val);
    $new[$key][] = $value;
}

print '<pre>';
print_r($new);
print '<pre>';
?>
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
Array
(
    [product_cat] => Array
        (
            [0] => 24
        )

    [style_cat] => Array
        (
            [0] => 97
            [1] => 98
            [2] => 100
            [3] => 104
        )

    [stone_count_cat] => Array
        (
            [0] => 110
            [1] => 109
            [2] => 111
        )

)
```

**DEMO:** https://eval.in/980195

Answer (score 1):

You can also do like this:

```
$new = array();
foreach( $array as $val) {
    $tmp = explode('-', $val);
    $new[$tmp[0]][] = $tmp[1];
}
```